# Define an equality operator for floats with tolerance: (~=)

Tags: f#, operator-overloading

I currently have the function:

```
let equal x1 x2 = abs(x1 - x2) < tolerance
```

to check for equality with some tolerance since we are checking floats so they won't be exactly equal.

How can I make this a binary infix operator on floats instead, as in x ~= y?

I tried:

```
type System.Double with
static member (~-) (this, that: System.Double) =
    equal this that
```

but then it says that I extension methods cannot provide operator overload

I tried then to inherit from System.Double and do the same:

```
type double() =
inherit System.Double()
static member (==) (this, that: double) =
    equal this that
```

but it complains that I cannot inherit from a "sealed" type

How would you then define a type double with this operator overload that acts like a normal System.Double ("float" in F#) but with this operator overload method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let (=~) x1 x2 = abs(x1 - x2) < tolerance
```

Comment: thanks ! apparently I cannot use that operator, though. Many other operators also don't work so I had to use "==" instead

Comment: Strange. Works fine for me. Make sure `tolerance` is a `float`. What version of F# are you using? What do you get if you send the definition above to FSI and use it?

Comment: @Mau I can show you exactly here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52465/f-invalid-infix-operator

Comment: @Mau and yes "tolerance" is a float and I'm using VS 2013. It thinks it's a prefix operator if I use ~=.